# How Do I Deal With This C++ Multimap Destructor?

Tags: c++, destructor, multimap

I am a beginner in C++ working on simple program and I ran into an issue which left me stumped... I do not understand where the memory is leaking. I understand more precisely, but I cannot write the destructor correctly. I ask for help.

Here is the class DBMAP

```
class DBMAP
{
    private:
        multimap < int, Volkov_1* > setMAP;
    public:
        DBMAP() {};
        DBMAP(DB& db)(DB & db)
        {
            db.copyM(*this);
        };
        void addM(Volkov_1* b)
        {
            setMAP.insert(pair<int, Volkov_1*>(*b->x, b));
        };
        ~DBMAP()
        //for (multimap< int, Volkov_1* >::iterator it = setMAP.begin(); it != setMAP.end(); ++it)
        // delete* it;;??

};
```

Comment: Use smart-pointers instead of raw pointers

Comment: How do you determine where memory is leaking? Post the diagnostic output of whatever tool you have used.

Comment: Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Otherwise people wont be able to help you competently.

Comment: and yes, explain what is meant to happen. Why do you store raw pointers? Are they to be considered owning, or not? If owning, why not use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` and not worry about it? If not, why not use `std::reference_wrapper` and convey the non-ownership? Post a full program that others can test, and a statement of what it's doing.

Comment: @underscore_d, how can I contact you to transfer the whole project to you?

Comment: You can't. But again, you could at least explain what tool is reporting leaks, and why the class is storing raw pointers, and what the ownership semantics of those are meant to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
~DBMAP()
{
  for (multimap< int, Volkov_1* >::iterator it = setMAP.begin(); it != setMAP.end(); ++it)
      delete it->second;
}
```

A multimap iterator points to a pair of values. The first of the pair is the key, the second is the value. That's the pointer you want to delete.

Comment: I don't know why, but the same leaks occur. Rechecked everything, leaks come from this class.

Comment: @IvanBolshakov would be nice to show readers what you have checked and what is reporting these leaks...

Comment: can I drop the whole project for you somewhere?